# Use extern "C" in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, extern

I wondered, is there an alternative to `extern "C"` in Swift?
I want to write a simple Unity plugin, and as an Obj-C noob I'd like to do it in Swift if possible.
Right now I have a very basic Obj-C code to show UIAlertView using

```
extern "C" 
{ 
    void _addAlert() 
    //Whatever
}
```

And in Unity it's hooked up with

```
private static extern void _addAlert()
{
    //Same whatever
}
```

I'm looking for a way to use Swift instead of Obj-C.
Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting extern "C" to do in Swift? You cannot write C within Swift so being able to specify how it links is not even relevant. Swift can interface with C, but you cannot embed C within Swift.

Comment: @drewag Right now I have a very basic Obj-C code to show UIAlertView using
`extern "C"
{
    void _addAlert()
}
`
And in Unity it's hooked up with  `private static extern void (_addAlert()`

I'm looking for a way to use Swift instead of Obj-C.

Comment: So you are asking how to call Swift code from C, or more specifically from Unity. You should reword your question to ask that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Top-level functions from Swift [cannot be used](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_85) from C/Objective-C. So obviously you will not be able to link to it from C/Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Swift in combination with Unity. I've done it.

You will have to create a "wrapper class" in Objective-C that sits between the C-functions called by Mono and the Swift code you've created.

This post explains how to call Swift from Objective-C: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/

Don't forget to set your target build to iOS 7.0 as a lower SDK does not support Swift.